# Parallel processing in cloud with python

Tags: python, apache-spark, parallel-processing, cloud

Having python-pandas knowledge and a scalable cloud, what is the best way to implement a parallel computation in cloud? (I have only one machine with many cpu, not many machines)

The cloud I currently have is an Amazon one, with windows server (scalable up to 40 cpu and 160GB of memory), but I could evaluate to use different cloud providers and different OS.

I thought to 2 possibilities:

- using python standard multiprocessing module (without any other sw)
- standalone spark with python interface

Spark should be more efficient than python multiprocessing? There are other ways I can evaluate?

Answer (score 1):

"To launch a Spark standalone cluster with the launch scripts, you should create a file called conf/slaves in your Spark directory, which must contain the hostnames of all the machines where you intend to start Spark workers, one per line."

See here : 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts

Good luck

Comment: ok thx but I'm thinking to use only one machine with 40 or more cpu, in cloud. In this way spark is really needed or I can use only python built-in multiprocessing module?

Comment: In this situation I don't think you should use Spark or any distributed-like tool. 
I would indeed advise you to use multiprocessing in Python. This way, you will profit of the large amount of CPU you have.